# Expectation and Lebesgue integration question

Tags: real-analysis, probability, lebesgue-integral

How can I show:

> If a random variable $Z$ has finite expectation $E(Z)$ (i.e., $Z$ is Lebesgue integrable), then $nP(|Z|>n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $nP(|Z|\gt n)=E(Z_n)$ with $Z_n=n\mathbf 1_{|Z|\gt n}$ and that $Z_n\to0$ almost surely. Hence all that is needed is to ensure that the integral of the limit is the limit of the integrals.

Lebesgue dominated theorem tells you that, if $|Z_n|\leqslant Y$ uniformly over $n$, for some integrable $Y$, everything works fine. Surely you have some idea about a candidate for $Y$...

Comment: A much better answer than mine. Sometimes I overthink problems...

Answer (score 1):

As in the [de la Vallée-Poussin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems),
 let $G$ be an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ so that $G(x)/x\to\infty$ but so slowly that $E(G(|Z|))<\infty$. Then by Markov's inequality, 
$$n\,P(|Z|>n)=n\,P(G(|Z|)>G(n))\leq {n\, E(G(|Z|))\over G(n)}\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that if nP(|Z|>n) tends to 0 it is not necessarily true that EZ is finite? I.e. does that mean that the converse is false?

Comment: Yes, the converse is false. $E(|Z|)$ is finite if and only if $\sum P(|Z|>n)<\infty$. So if $P(|Z|>n)=1/(n\log(n))$ then $E(|Z|)=\infty$ but $nP(|Z|>n)\to 0$.